# Failed to resolve Firebase crash library android 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to update my dependencies to compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2' but

All I get is:

```
Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.0.2'
```

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 9):

Installing latest version of google repository will help.

1. Go to the Menu bar > Tools > Android > SDK Manager
2. Click on Tab >    SDK Tools
3. Check and install 'Google Play Services' and 'Google Repository'
4. Now, click Sync and build your project again.